# Core data keep creating A Document Being Saved... folders

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using Core Data with a prepopulated Store with an entity that has Binary Data with External Storage checkbox enabled to save some large images externally, and every time I run the app in the simulator and executing  a fetch request, a new folder called "A Document Being Saved by AppName" inside Documents is created.

The folder contains some of the images I fetched when running the app.

The problem is this folder doesn't delete on application termination, and the app keeps increasing in size currently weighting several GB!

I have started this project using the default Xcode template with Core Data enabled.

Did I Miss something ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bill,

That folder is a temporary store for the externally saved BLOBs. The folder is normally emptied when the save is finished. If you crash though during the save, then the data is left behind for you to handle. I normally delete the directories on startup. Basically, if the BLOB isn't moved into the CD hidden BLOB directory, then it isn't in the DB. In my application, I've had no problem. Your mileage may vary.

Andrew

Comment: In my case, the directories were emptied, but remained on the device. When I added file sharing, I saw 120 empty directories in iTunes. Not very convenient. I don't think I had 120 crashes on the device, so I guess there is a bug in cleaning up. Could you perhaps share you code for cleaning up the empty directories?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Core Data it seems likely that you want the data that your app generates to persist, right? If so, then deleting its data store when the app terminates doesn't seem very helpful. (Also, the user really shouldn't care whether the app has actually terminated or not.) Perhaps your app should instead monitor the number of images it has stored and delete the old ones as it goes along?

Comment: The app uses a repopulated store. All the images are stored in a hidden folder created by core data called .AppName_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA . When I fetch an image, the app then creates the "Document Being Saved by AppName" folder, and duplicates the image there, like cache or something. After termination this folder should normally been deleted, since it contains duplicate data specifically only for a fetch request.